# How do I add CSS body classes for logged-in and logged-out users?

Tags: 8, theming, users

In Drupal 7 I would add a theme process function to add the body classes needed.

```
function template_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['classes_array'][] = $variables['is_front'] ? 'front' : 'not-front';
  // Add a class that tells us whether the page is viewed by an authenticated user or not.
  $variables['classes_array'][] = $variables['logged_in'] ? 'logged-in' : 'not-logged-in';
}
```

In [D8 this theme function exists](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/8.7.x) but they don't have all the variables need for users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I think I figured this out as in Drupal 8 it uses TWIG to print the body classes for content types or users we need.

In the html.html.twig

```
{%
  set body_classes = [
    logged_in ? 'user-logged-in',
    not root_path ? 'path-frontpage' : 'path-' ~ root_path|clean_class,
    node_type ? 'page-node-type-' ~ node_type|clean_class,
    db_offline ? 'db-offline',
    user.hasPermission('administer')  ? 'isAdmin',
    user.getRoles()|join(' role_')
  ]
%}
```

Then make sure this line is added to the body classes

```
   <body{{ attributes.addClass(body_classes) }}>
```

So if the user is logged out we can use the role class to identify them.

```
   .anonymous { }
```

Or we can use the [:not Css selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) 
:not

```
   :not.user-logged-in {}
```

Answer (score 2):

In html.html.twig and page.html.twig we have various variable available like `logged_in`, `is_front`, `is_admin` by default. Using these variables as condition we can add class to body tag. Some classes like `path-frontpage`, `page-node-type-*` are by default present in node and they is no need to add them explicitly.